# Issue opening chrome with selenium webdriver - No internet Connection

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to open Chrome and scripts are written to goto some URL

When I use the script in any other machine it launches the chrome browser and goes to the URL.

But only in one of the machines I face a issue like No internet connection after it launches the browser. But I am able to access internet in the machine with the normal browsers(other than the browser launched by webdriver)

I tried with ChromeDriver 2.33 and 2.34. Both had the same issue.

Could someone help me in this

Comment: Any proxy settings on this machine?

Comment: I had a proxy and when I removed it, the issue was solved

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my computer resolved this